# Merging multiple tables from multiple databases with all rows and columns

Tags: sql

I have 30 databases from a survey application that all have a table of results with approximately 100 columns in each. Most of the columns are identical but each survey seems to have a unique column or two added in with no real pattern (these are the added questions and results of the survey). As I am working on the statement to join all of the tables into one large master table the code is getting quite complex. Is  there a more efficient way to merge these tables from multiple databases and just select all rows and columns so it will merge if the column exists and create if it encounters a new column?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am just stating this project. Someone before me was using myphp to create surveys. All 30 tables are the same survey but as he would change questions text or add questions he would create a new database. This has left me trying to do one complete report on the survey with a very fragmented database structure and no record of where all the changes were made. I was hoping to find some way to get it all in one large container to start working with the data and see what we have.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question which DBMS you are using ("myphp" is not a database I have ever heard of)

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an automatic way to merge a bunch of similar, but not quite the same, tables into one.  At least, not in any database system that I know of.

You could possibly automate something like that with a fairly simple script that relies on your database's [information schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) (or equivalent).

However, with only 30 tables and only a column or two different in each, I'm not sure it's worth it.  A manual approach, with copying and pasting and making minor changes, would probably be faster.

Also, consider whether the "extra" columns that are unique to individual tables need to go into the combined table.  The point of making a big single table is to process/analyze all the data together.  If something only applies to a single source, this isn't possible.